# How many references exist in this three-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays

Assume the following array

```
int myarray [][][] = new int [12][12][3];
```

How many references are generated by this array declaration?

I think, it should be 12*12*3, as exactly how many elements can be stored in the array.

However, my colleague thinks, there are 12 + 12*12 because there are 12 references in "myarray" directly and 144 references that point from the second to the third dimension.

But how can there be less references then actual values stored in this array?

Comment: How do *you* define a reference exactly?

Comment: Hint: a single int value is no reference.

Comment: In my opinion is it 12 * 12 * 3.

Comment: In this case a reference is a unique pointer to a value/object in the array. For clarification: I need this to estimate the size of the given array (assume a reference needs 4/8 bytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get straight what Java programmers mean by "reference".  A reference refers to an object value, including an array, as opposed to a primitive value such as an `int`, which doesn't refer to any other object -- it's just a value.  There are 12*12*3 *values*, but not the same number of references.

There are no references contained in each lowest-level array, because the base type is primitive - `int`.  This means that the last length of 3 doesn't have any influence on the number of references.

In Java multi-dimensional arrays are implements as arrays of arrays.  The middle value 12 means 12 references each to arrays of length 3.  The first value 12 means 12 references each to 12 arrays described by the middle value.  Your colleague is close in that this means that the number of references contained in this multidimensional array is 12 + 12*12, or 156.  In the 3D array, that's 12 outer references to 12 2D arrays, plus 144 inner references to 144 1D arrays.  Including the reference `myArray` itself, that's 157.

Comment: Interesting, I assume those primitive values are nevertheless stored in the heap? But given the reference to a[0][0], how does the JVM know where the values of the primitive are exactly stored? Doing some arithmetic with the reference and the memory space of the lowest-level array? So in the Array-Object primitive values are stored using a constant address pattern?

Comment: The JVM will follow the array references at each dimension.  It knows where `a` is, so based on where `a` is, it finds `a[0]` and follows that reference to the inner array.  Then from there it can find `a[0][0]`.  It's not specified how a JVM may lay out its array memory within the heap, but it would make the most sense for it to be continuous memory.  Primitive values that exist in an array are stored in the heap memory of the array.